# Find the centroid of a cluster in tslearn soft-dtw / dtw clustering

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis

I'm using `tslearn` to perform time-series clustering. I was trying to find out what I should do if I want to find the centroid of each cluster but had no luck so far. The document mentioned a "barycenter" that sounds like the centroid to me, but it didn't say how to calculate the barycenter. Does anyone happen to have experience in this area? Thanks! Below is the code I use so far to do the clustering work.

```
for j in [2,3]: # try 2 and 3 clusters 
    km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=j, metric="softdtw")
    labels = km.fit_predict(ts_intention_list)
    silhouetteScore = silhouette_score(ts_intention_list, labels, metric="softdtw")
    print(f"\nLabels for {j} clusters: {labels}")

    num_of_clusters_list.append(j)
    silhouetteScore_list.append(silhouetteScore)
    print(f"{j} clusters, score is {silhouetteScore}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the cluster centroids with the `cluster_centers_` attribute of the `TimeSeriesKMeans` object; you might use it in your code as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# For 9 clusters
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True, constrained_layout=True)

km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=9, metric="softdtw", n_jobs=-1)

# data is our (N, M, d) shaped time series
y_pred = km.fit_predict(data)

for yi, axis in zip(range(n_clusters), axes.ravel()):
    # Plot all the snippets used in faded-out grey
    for xx in data[y_pred == yi]:
        axis.plot(xx.ravel(), "k-", alpha=0.2)

    # Plot the cluster centroids in bold red
    axis.plot(km.cluster_centers_[yi].ravel(), "r-")
```

A full example of is given in the documentation, [here](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/clustering/plot_kmeans.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-clustering-plot-kmeans-py)